# VS2015 Item templates

Tags: mvvm-light

I got MVVMLight installed in VS2015 and can create a new MVVM universal windows project. There are now item templates for new pages however, so what is the best way to create them? I can copy the mainpage, but there are a lot of references to pages and viewmodels in other files so I doubt it's going to work this way.

Regards,
Stan

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install an extension to get these. Tools > Extensions and updates. Then search for mvvmlight.